# NSTimeInterval in seconds between dates = nan

Tags: ios, nstimeinterval

```
NSTimeInterval executionTime = [self.EndDownloadTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.StartDownloadTime];
NSLog(@"Execution Time: %f", executionTime);
```

Result is always "nan". When i switch EndDownloadTime and StartDownloadTime, time is "0.00000"

StartDownloadTime and EndDownloadTime are types of NSDate.

How do i get the seconds between the two dates?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you are doing looks correct to me.  Log the start and end time values and add them to your question.

Comment: When you are debugging a problem and everything looks correct but the code is failing then an assumption must be wrong. There are two assumptions here (at least): the values of self.EndDownloadTime and self.StartDownloadTime. NSLog them or use the debugger examining the values as you step through. Note: In Cocoa* properties and variables and method names by convention begin with a lower case letter, case names with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is a better method, check the docs when things seem complicated:

```
NSTimeInterval executionTime = [self.EndDownloadTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.StartDownloadTime];
```

When you are debugging a problem and everything looks correct but the code is failing then an assumption must be wrong. There are two assumptions here (at least): the values of self.EndDownloadTime and self.StartDownloadTime. NSLog them or use the debugger examining the values as you step through.

Check everything:

```
NSLog(@"StartDownloadTime: %@", self.StartDownloadTime);
NSLog(@"StartloadTimeInterval: %f", [self.StartDownloadTime timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSLog(@"EndDownloadTime: %@", self.EndDownloadTime);
NSLog(@"EndDownloadTimeInterval: %f", [self.EndDownloadTime timeIntervalSince1970]);

NSTimeInterval executionTime = [self.EndDownloadTime timeIntervalSince1970] - [self.StartDownloadTime timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"Execution Time: %f", executionTime);
```

Note: In Cocoa* properties and variables and method names by convention begin with a lower case letter, class names with an uppercase letter. This makes it easier for others to understand your code.

Comment: `StartDownloadTime: (null)
StartloadTimeInterval: 0.000000
EndDownloadTime: (null)
EndDownloadTimeInterval: 0.000000
Execution Time: 0.000000` The problem is the "null", correct? But when i set the date to a label, it works correctly

Comment: Now i know the problem, but i don't know how to solve it. In a first method, startDownloadTime is called an it returns the right value. But when a call startDownloadTime in another method, it returns (null). But i didn't change the variable.. :/

Comment: Please do two things: 1. Create a new question with the new problem. 2. Accept answers that provided the answer or are most helpful. This will increase your reputation and capabilities on SO.

Comment: @Velocity - before creating a new question, try to figure it out.  Search code for touches to the two NSDates, implement a custom setter - (void)setStartDownloadTime:(NSDate *)date and add a breakpoint, etc.  It seems this was a premature question, please don't create another.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right. Try this and print value of variables to know if the two dates are correct.

---

```
NSTimeInterval executionTime = [self.EndDownloadTime timeIntervalSince1970] - [self.StartDownloadTime timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"Execution Time: %f", executionTime);
```

---